# Should a ORM have a single database connection for all requests?

Tags: database, orm, backend

A lot of sources on the web say it is best to make a connection pool or new connection for each request. I understand the reasoning why this is the case (more scalable) and I prefer it this way. But if you don't get 100 requests per minute, is it worth the extra time for each request for the db connection to establish? I would like to hear your different standpoints on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand the benefits of making a connection pool then it's up to you to decide what to do. It's generally a good thing to do if you want a fast reply time and expect any decent amount of requests.

In this link you can find a detailed explanation: https://dev.to/digi0ps/connection-pooling-what-and-why-bom